# Should variables in VB.Net be declared at the beginning of a routine?

Tags: vb.net

I guess I'm a bit confused about best practice here. In VBA, the recommendation has always been to put all of your variables at the top of your routine(property or sub or function). I can't seem to find any definitive answer anywhere that mentions whether or not this is good practice in more modern OO languages. I am learning VB.Net and would like to cultivate good habits the first time around. Are there advantages to either way of doing things?

Comment: Originally this was necessary: back in ye olden days C and Pascal compilers/interpreters required all function-local variables to be declared before any actual instructions, this included loop variables (e.g. the `i` in `for(int i = 0; ...`). Compilers written in the past 30 years don't require this anymore, but the habit stuck in many people's minds. I do see some advantages for the sake of didacticism, but if you have many variables that only exist in a branch or loop then it just becomes silly.

Comment: In addition to the point @Dai makes, I think it is useful to declare variables to have the smallest possible scope. That means variables that are used (for example) only inside a loop should be declared inside the loop.

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense. I'll have to retrain my brain :-)

Comment: The concept of Block Scope changed the usefulness of top-declarations as well.  Scratch vars can be reused rather than proliferating.  I still put "important ones" at the top, the rest...not so much.  The ability of VS to tell you what any var is by hovering the mouse also makes it less important to be able to find a var to see what it is declared as.

Comment: I think it is fair to say that best practice has changed in the last few decades. I now declare as late as possible, although I still tend to put module-level variables all at the top.

Comment: You need to develop a style that makes the code easy to understand.  A module should only be up to around 300 lines of code.  You should separate sections of a module clearly by adding white space (returns a margins).   Global variables should be put at top of module and local variables at top of sections (after a few blank line) to make then easy to locate.

Comment: Well if one of you want to put your comments as an answer I'll mark it.